# Convert 'Container' type data into serialization without X++ Conpeek

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-365-operations

I have a table where one of the columns contains container data stored as a hexadecimal string.
I'd like to import this data into an external program to read the contents.

Dynamics Axapta provides the X++ method 'conpeek' but that would require asking the database engineer to run a batch script to decompress the data I need ahead of time.

Instead I'd like to know how the format of the variable type works so i can read in the hexadecimal and convert it into a CSV or something using a more portable and accessible language.

Comment: Take a look at https://abraaxapta.blogspot.com/2011/06/accessing-dynamics-ax-containers-from.html. Some considerations are nested containers or complex types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers are not meant to be read by any but AX itself. Containers do not have a documented layout, but it is doable to reverse engineer it.

- [A SQL `conPeek` function](https://abraaxapta.blogspot.com/2011/06/accessing-dynamics-ax-containers-from.html).
- [A C++ binary reader](https://pastebin.com/XHrwmrVG) that reads AX binary files ([BinaryIO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/dynamics.ax.application.binaryio)). It also contains method to read containers.

Comment: Jan I think yours is the correct answer as that link does detail a solution that worked for Mr.Thimm. I can also confirm that the solution is very similar to what I found reverse engineering the container format while I waited for answers.

Comment: @Michael.C - you could also make a service endpoint that could serialize containers for consumption externally.